# ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Why is this ambiguous?

```
// In class declaration
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_list {
    void for_each(std::function<void(T&)> _consumer);
    void for_each(std::function<void(const T&)> _consumer) const;
}
```

```
// Calling for_each
threadsafe_list<bool> list;

std::function<void(const bool&)> print = [](const bool& _bool) {
    std::cout << (_bool ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
};

// Warning: for_each is ambiguous
list.for_each(print);

// This is OK
list.for_each([](const bool& _bool) { std::cout << (_bool ? "True" : "False") << std::endl; });
```

Why is the above ambigous? One of the for_each is meant for const while the other isn't.
Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726740/c-error-operator-2-overloads-have-similar-conversions

Comment: Reopened. This has **nothing to do with lambdas**. It's simply about overload resolution for a function that takes two arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible overload resolutions for the first call, each involving a conversion:

1. Choose the first overload, convert `std::function<void(const bool&)>` → `std::function<void(bool&)>`
2. Choose the second overload, convert `threadsafe_list<bool>&` → `const threadsafe_list<bool>&`

Neither conversion is better than the other because they apply to different arguments.

For the second call, one is better than the other because the worse one converts both arguments (the lambda to `std::function` and `list` to `const threadsafe_list<bool>&`).

To resolve this, you can add yet another overload which would be a better match than either of the original two:

```
void for_each(std::function<void(T&)> _consumer) const;
```

or, alternatively, just remove `std::function` completely to ensure an exact match of the argument:

```
template <typename F>
void for_each(F _consumer);
template <typename F>
void for_each(F _consumer) const;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason there is ambiguity in the first case is that `list` isn't `const`, so the implicit argument that becomes `this` has a qualification conversion, and the other overload has a `std::function<void(const bool&)>` to `std::function<void(bool&)>` conversion.

The other case isn't ambiguous because there is a conversion for both arguments in the `const` case, but only for `_consumer` in the mutable case.